# Where to find this Client.php laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I upgraded my php version in WSL to 7.4 and I am running an application built with laravel-5.5.

When I run `php artisan` in the command line I got this error

In Client.php line 1551:

> Undefined variable: version

There are many $version available where do I find this Client.php this error talking about?

There is no log record in the log about this.

Thanks

Comment: It's the sentry error if you are using it too...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To do solve this temporarily I did this

```
return $version ?? '0.0.0';
```

on 
`vendor\sentry\sentry\lib\Raven\Client.php:1551`

and change `$path{0}` to `$path[0]`

on `vendor\sentry\sentry\lib\Raven\Client.php:331`

Comment: Worked for ```Laravel 5.6``` with ```php 7.4```

Comment: but it is not the proper solution. Can't modify vendor files that way!

Comment: I am saying temporarily.. I am not recommending it

Comment: Not unless sentry update there code, when running composer update you need to do this again, not unless there's other way like extending