# PHP composer exhausting memory... Why? What is happening?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

Attempting to initialize a PHP/Laravel project (by running `composer install`), I encountered exactly the same problem as described here: [Where to find this Client.php laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59155247/where-to-find-this-client-php-laravel)

I tried to updgrade the package that did not interact well with newer PHP version, by using `composer require` with the attempt to upgrade the offending package, but it did not go well:

```
$ composer require sentry/sentry-laravel:1.8.0
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in phar:///usr/local/Cellar/composer/1.10.7/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php on line 223

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in phar:///usr/local/Cellar/composer/1.10.7/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php on line 223

Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors for more info on how to handle out of memory errors.
```

I read in the documentation how I can increase the memory limit (yes - most easily by setting `COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT` environment variable before running `composer` like so many mention), but before I do that, I would like to understand is there something wrong with the project to exhaust 1536Mb memory limit, and if so how to understand and fix the problem? More specifically, what else does this command do than replace the version requirement in the `composer.json` file? What could go wrong if I just manually edit the `composer.json` file, and run `compose install` from clean table (after wiping the `vendor/` directory and whatever else gets written to the project directory) - would version conflicts with other dependencies detected?

Comment: If you put it in `composer.json`, does it work? Try removing vendor dir and `composer install`. Do you have any post update scripts in composer.json?

Comment: I don't have the solution for "why", but you can alleviate this by adding an "environment variable" to your CLI command: `COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer ...`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your setup. It's just that composer actually needs a load of memory to resolve the whole dependency tree.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62043521/2188922 this answer may give you some lead to how to arrange swap to overcome this problem

Comment: @TimeLewis... Sure, seems obvious, but I just do not dare to do that, because I need to use the computer (Mac) for other work too, and have the 16gb of RAM almost exhausted and SSD almost full causing immense trashing just today even without such attempt.

Answer (score 2):

> More specifically, what else does this command do than replace the version requirement in the `composer.json` file?

It also tries to install new version of dependency, and to do that it needs to check if this is possible (new version does not conflict with other dependencies) and what else needs to be done (install/upgrade subdependencies). In practice it means complete rebuilding dependency tree, which is complicated process and requires a lot of memory.

Manually editing `composer.json` does not give you nothing, because it will not install this dependency. You still need to run `composer update` to do that, which will require rebuilding dependency tree and result the same memory problems as with `require` command.

Comment: I forgot to explain the obvious, rerunning `compose install` from clean table after editing the file... (I will probably try this later, the question was written with the wish to get insight about the background of this failure.)

Comment: (1.6Gb for building and checking the dependency graph just seems grazy, I do not understand why this should happen.)

Comment: In my understanding, `composer update` will update all the packages what is something I do not want to do for an application running in production with hundreds of thousands users. Not without comprehensive testing.

Comment: `composer install` will install dependencies from `composer.lock` (previously calculated for old `composer.json`), so your changes in `composer.json` will be ignored. `composer update` is indeed a bad idea in this case, I was mentioning it only to point that manually editing of `composer.json` will not help with memory problems.

Comment: You may try to update composer to latest version: 2.0 branch has some big improvements in memory consumption.

Answer (score -2):

When I come across an issue like this I temporarily let `composer` have unlimited memory:

```
COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer require sentry/sentry-laravel:1.8.0
```

Answer (score -4):

try to remove your vendor file and then keep going composer install

Comment: The author says that his composer his running out of memory, which is a common case. Removing the vendor directory will not help there.

Comment: This answer obviously missed some details.

Comment: Removing the vendor directory (and whatever appears after `composer install`) + editing the `compose.json` + rerunning `composer install` again is what I wish to try if I need to deal with this again. You are on the same  tracks that I was thinking, I think.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it - why should that provide a different experience?